How to save EML files and attachments within SharePoint that already have folder names and save them based on email subject
I made it like this is it correct?



I hope someone helps me
Thanks

What are the issues your are facing? In my experience, while constructing the name of the file based on the  Subject of the email, I had to remove the special chars as they are not allowed in the name. Also, added the timestamp in case two emails received with the same subject.

I'm having trouble building a flow in Power Automate. I can't seem to find the right formula to save EML files and attachments to a specific SharePoint folder called and save it folder name base on subject

The email body along with the attachments should be saved into a document library with eml extension. These files then can be opened in outlook. It can be the root folder of the library or any other folder in the library. Is that what you want?

I meant to say, there are various ways. Based on your flow, you're trying to extract the attachment and save as individual file in a SPO library, right? In that case, you will have the attachment file extension, not EML extension

That's right, the file is in the form of an eml and its contents (jpg, excel, word, pdf). but the eml file can be saved in the sharepoint folder based on the email subject. because in the Sharepoint folder there are many folders, so we can enter the EML file via email.

Please see the example showing how to save the entire email body with attachments as an eml file into a SPO document library.
Please note that, file name is constructed from the subject of the email by removing special char, and also adding timestamp


Expressions
varSubject:

replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(trim(string(triggerBody()?['subject'])), ':', ''), '%', ''), '#', ''), '*', ''), '<', ''), '>', ''), '?', ''), '/', ''), '"', '')

varSubjectLength:

length(variables('varSubject'))

varCurrentDateEST:

convertFromUtc(utcNow(), 'Eastern Standard Time', 'MMddyyyyTHHmmss')

EmailFileName:

concat(if(greater(variables('varSubjectLength'), 30), substring(variables('varSubject'), 0, 30), variables('varSubject')), '-', variables('varCurrentDateEST'), rand(10,99), '.eml')



here i try to modif but still can't success...

What are you modifying? What error messages are you getting? Please respond with details for me to understand otherwise I can't help
